# Raphael Canvas parent div having resize CSS3 property doesn't work well: SVG is above canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, raphael

I want to implement the ability to allow users to resize the SVG by just dragging it with the trigger in the lower right corner introduced with  `resize: both`, but it is just weird:

Whenever I resize it to min-width and min-height (which is my SVG min-width and min-height) I cannot resize the SVG anymore because the trigger is not "draggable" / clickable anymore.

I tried everything: from playing around with z-index, to wrapping another div around it.

This is the status I mean:
http://puu.sh/8tIGJ.png

http://jsfiddle.net/UW7bY/

Another issue I have is that the canvas is a little higher in size than the SVG... I can only fix it by using `display: flex`, but that doesn't work well with `resize`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are getting into troubles using such a CSS `resize` rule: bad event listening, the resize element is not an element, so no z-index trick. Have a draggable div on top of the canvas, you will avoid some headaches.

Comment: Thank you. That worked better, but I am not satisfied with the result. I think I will have to implement a button to enable a mode for editing the size of the SVG..